# php: html_entity_decode not converting &sdot; to simple character dot

Tags: php, html-entities

I have been trying to convert sdot like this

```
html_entity_decode("&sdot;");
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
html_entity_decode('&sdot;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

The default character set being converted *to* is ISO-8859-1, which cannot represent `&sdot;`. Specify a character set that can represent that character and it will be converted.

Comment: Awesome, yes it works. Thanks. In 8 minutes I can mark it as correct.